# How to make cortana start your program

Tags: windows-10-universal, cortana

I just started developing a small app for Windows 10 universal.
And I am trying to use Cortana in it.
What I would like for a start is to have Cortana start my app when I say:
Hey Cortana start [myAppName]
It looks like this is not working by default, and I could not find any tutorial about that.
Any ideas what I should do ?

Answer (score 2):

I did a tutorial on this with the Quick Start for UWP guide. You can take a look at it here:

http://microsoft.github.io/UWPQuickStart/docs/challenges/cortana-integration.html

If that's not enough to get you rolling, please let me know where you're running into issues and I'll see if I can help further.

Comment: Do you know a way to do this with a C# app? not a XAML.
My project is a Universal Holographic DirectX 11 App. and by default it does not contain any XAML.

Comment: The integration between Windows 10 and Cortana is automatic. If you install an app named "Star Wars", you can call Cortana "Hey Cortana, start Star Wars" and the app is launched. I think that Cortana recognizes your app based on the display name declared in the manifest file.

You don't need to write any XAML or C# to obtain this.

Comment: The code in my example is all C# code. Sure, I've got some of the events coming off the XAML "OnLaunched" events, but as long as your C# code calls the VoiceCommandDefinitionManager methods the way I point out in the first section, it should work. At what stage are you running into the problems?